# Script to extract part of txt file to an excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
category test_1

    aaa.com; test info - tw
    bbb.com; test info - al

category “test_2”

    ccc.com; test info - al
    ddd.com; test info - tw
    eee.com; test info - tw

category test_3

    fff.com
    ggg.com; test info - al
    hhh.com; test info - tw
    iii.com; test info - al
```

I need help editing a Python script that pulls a portion of the txt file and exports it to an excel file. For example, if I want to export the entries in category test_1, the script would produce the following output in an excel file.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa.com | test info - tw |  |
| 2 | bbb.com | test info - al |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |

I have tried to use the code below

My txt file is saved on my desktop as autotest.txt

```
file=open(“autotest.txt”,’r’)
data=file.read()
categories=data.split(‘category’)
dict_format={}
for categor_data in categories:
    items=categor_data.split(‘\n’)
    dict_format[items[0].replace(“ “, “”)=items[1:]

for name in dict_format:
    print(name)

print(“Which category to export to .csv?”)
answer=input()

with open(answer+”.csv”,’w’) as csv:
    for row in dict_format[answer][:-1]:
        if row != “”:
            csv.write(row.replace(“;”,”,”)+”\n”)

    csv.write(dict_format[answer][-1].replace(“;”,”,”))
    csv.close()
```

When I run this code, it works correctly and returns an excel file for test_1 and test_3 but “test_2” does not return a file. I am not sure why this occurs as I am accounting for and entering “test_2” in the question including the quotes. I have also tried entering it in the question without and get a file but it doesn’t contain the entries.

Any help as to why the quotes is causing this error is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: that's not valid python code. I'd replace the angular quotes `”` as iirc that happens sometimes on apple devices like when typing on iphone for example.

Comment: and i suspect quotes are largely the issue here because if you notice for cat2 you define it like `category “test_2”` which means when you enter input,, you need to enter it exactly with angular quotes too like `“test_2”` for example.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I do enter it as “test_2” and it doesn’t return an excel file.

Comment: The problem is some of the categories in the database are named without parentheses and some are named with them. The code works perfectly fine for categories that aren’t within parentheses. @rv.kvetch

Answer (score 0):

When printing the keys:

```
print(dict_format.keys())
```

Return:

```
dict_keys([“, ‘test_1’, ‘“test_2”’, ‘test_3’])
```

Changing:

```
dict_format[items[0].replace(“ “, “”)]=items[1:]
```

To this:

```
item_name=items[0].replace(“ “, “”)
item_name=item_name.strip(‘“‘)
dict_format[item_name]=items[1:]
```

This changes how the program reads the category and produces the expected output.